# The difference between 書物、図書 and 本

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

What are the differences between these three words. They all seem to translate to "books".

書物、図書 and 本

Comment: And 書籍, and 単行本, and 文庫本… The Japanese love their books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`本` typically means hard-bounded volume. `図書` can equally refer to magazines as well. `書物` has an academic flavour. See Tsuyosh Ito's comment below.

Comment: All of 本, 図書, and 書物 can refer to magazines as well.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi_Ito In some cases I think so. But it's not the most salient. If you hear `本`, what comes to mind immediately is not a magazine but a bound book. If you hear `図書`, that is somewhat neutral.

Comment: I agree to your comment.  I think that the problem is the use of “can refer to” in your answer.  Probably what you wanted to say is not whether each word _can_ refer to magazines or not, but what it _typically_ refers to.  I agree that 図書 is more neutral about whether it refers to a book or a magazine.